# R: agrep with vector pattern

Tags: r, fuzzy-search, agrep

I have a vector of patterns, and need to use `agrep` on them. The problem is that `agrep` seems to take only one pattern at a time.

```
patt <- c("test","10 Barrel")
lut  <- c("1 Barrel","10 Barrel Brewing","Harpoon 100 Barrel Series","resr","rest","tesr")

for (i in 1:length(patt)) {
  print(agrep(patt[i],lut,max=1,v=T))
}
```

Result:

```
[1] "rest" "tesr"
[1] "1 Barrel"                  "10 Barrel Brewing"         "Harpoon 100 Barrel Series"
```

`for` is slow on long patterns, thus attempting to do it in vectorized form:

```
VecMatch1 = function(string, stringVector){
  stringVector[agrep(string, stringVector, max = 1)]
}
a = VecMatch1(patt,lut)

Warning message:
In agrep(string, stringVector, max = 1) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

May be functions like `lapply` etc can help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `lapply`:

```
lapply(patt, agrep, x=lut, max.distance=c(cost=1, all=1), value=TRUE)

[[1]]
[1] "rest" "tesr"

[[2]]
[1] "1 Barrel"                  "10 Barrel Brewing"         "Harpoon 100 Barrel Series"
```

You can probably get faster performance with dplyr or data.table.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I tried `lapply` but used wrong syntax - didn't put  function in proper place

Comment: Turned out, both methods have comparable speed.

Comment: How would you approach it with dplyr or data.table?